# Is excess of potassium as strenuous and harmful for kidneys as excess of sodium or worst?

Tags: kidney

I was wondering since channels of body's cell membranes deal with potassium and sodium ions differently and considering the fact that potassium lowers blood pressure and sodium raises it :

1. **What is the most expensive in energy for kidneys** between having to excrete an excess of potassium and an excess of sodium, for a healthy person and without considering blood pressure? Which process is the longest?
2. I know that insulin tends to make kidneys reabsorb sodium but **does glucose help the kidneys to get rid of the excess potassium in any way?**
3. **On long term, what is the most harmful for the kidneys' circulatory system** considering blood pressure and in the case of a kidney failure? For tubules and nephrons?